# Php file upload works when upload photo to server but cant get the file name

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files to server using dropzone.js in client side. The problem is that the file will get uploaded to the destination folder in server but i can't get the file name!

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;
    $conn = new Database;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)){
        echo $fileName;

    } 

}
```

This won't echo anything. I am trying to upload multiple files too and is the same problem!

Comment: Could you add result of `print_r($_FILES);` to your question, please? I feel that it will answer your question instantly.

Comment: It doesn't print anything! Is just blank

Comment: Then problem is not in PHP but in dropzone.js params or form attributes you use. So spend time debugging what you have, checking what exactly is being sent to server, etc. If my memory doesn't fail me, dropzone.js sends files in separate ajax instead of refreshing page you are on after upload.

Comment: But that's weird because the file will be uploaded to the folder destination that is defined in php file inside the if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) statement

Comment: Ok. Do you know how to open network console in your browser (F12 for Chrome) - check, what requests are being sent. I'm sure that dropzone.js sends file in background - that's why file is uploaded correctly, then you reload page and don't see any $_FILES because it is another request. If you don't know why it happens: read how PHP works, how to debug code, how to use F12, etc. StackOverflow is the latest thing you need to use to solve your problem

Comment: First of all, be sure there's no errors on uploaded file **$_FILES['file']['error']** should be 0 (zero). More info on: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: @Triby, did you read other comments? Especially one that says $_FILES is empty.

Comment: @iXCray, no i don't reload page! It is the same request. And yes, dropzone does send the requests in background!
I wanna take the name of the file and store it in database.

Comment: If you say that file is being uploaded to the destination folder, then I see no obstacles to just add a code that insert row into your database. Dropzone sends request in background - that's where file is being uploaded, that's where you can read print_r($_FILES) from F12 console network response, that's where you add row into database. Everything works from your comments, you just don't know where to look.

Comment: $conn = new Database; - that's now how you insert file name into database. There definitely should be more code.

Comment: well it worked at least. It seams didn't notice a mistake in query! Anyway thank you guys!